# What's the correct way to implement a sparse lookup table in 8051 assembly? (Keys have 2 bits set, 1 per nibble)

Tags: assembly, lookup, lookup-tables, 8051

I am programming an 8052 microcontroller, and need a procedure that converts the following 8-bit input into an arbitrary set of 8-bit outputs.

All 16 possible input values are of the form `0xHL`, where `H` and `L` are either 1, 2, 4, or 8.

The 16 output values are more or less arbitrary, so I shan't list them here.

I am struggling to find the "correct" way to implement this function. My instinct is to make a lookup table in code memory, but these 16 inputs are so far apart from each other, that there would be a lot of unnecessarily wasted code memory. For example, if I defined some `TABLE_START:` section in my code, there would be one entry at location `#TABLE_START + 0x01`, and another entry all the way at `#TABLE_START + 0x88`. That's over 100 bytes of memory for 16 entries!

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: for 16 entries a linear lookup seems simplest. Ie loop for i = 0 to 15. Even a binary chop seems like overkill.

Comment: Does this need to be fast, or do you want to optimize for code+data size?  Or somewhere in between, small but not *too* slow?  (i.e. is linear search through a 32-byte table of key:value pairs fast enough, like pm100 suggested?  Or maybe bit-position search to map the low and high bit-positions within their nibbles, then combine those to a 0..15 index?)

Comment: Correctness of code is pretty well defined. You must have other criteria when you say "correct"

Comment: @PeterCordes It's for a keypad, so ideally fast. That being said, the more I think about it, the more I wonder if just creating a large, inefficient table for a simple movc a, @a+dptr might be best. There would just be so much empty space.

Your suggestions about "bit-position search" sounds interesting, but I don't quite know what you mean. My current implementation is converting the input H and L nibbles of 1,2,4,8  to the values 0, 1, 2, 3 respectively, and having the final value be 4*(converted high) + (converted low). From there I'm thinking of doing a lookup table to my desired outputs

Comment: Reacting on a key press is so slow compared to the common speed of even an 8052, your solution does not need to be fast. Go for a simple solution, simple to write, simple to read, simple to understand. When thinking about memory usage, consider the size of the needed code if you use "compression" or a "multi-stage" algorithm.

Comment: did you consider a lookup table to convert H and L from 8,4,2,1 to 3,2,1,0 and simply shift them together? lookup[H] << 2 + lookup[L] ? shouldn't be too slow and reduces the sice of your jump table to just 8 + 16*2 = 40 bytes. Ok, reading your comment I start thinking thats what you already do? :)